# Hexagon Polygon of different color triangles inside using clip-path CSS

Tags: css, frontend, web-frontend, clip-path

[image: How can I make this using clip-path]

I want to make the following hexagon with different triangle colors using clip-path (CSS).

I tried using :polygon(6 coordinates) and giving color via background color (which makes a hexagon but only one color). But I'm not able to make this different color. I don't know if gradient will work too.
Please Help thank you.

Answer (score 3):

conic-gradient can do the job:

```css
.box {
  width:200px;
  clip-path: polygon(0% 25%,0% 75%,50% 100%,100% 75%,100% 25%,50% 0%);
  background:
    conic-gradient(
       red    0 60deg,
       blue   0 120deg,
       green  0 180deg,
       purple 0 240deg, 
       pink   0 300deg, 
       yellow 0 360deg);
}

.box:before {
  content:"";
  display:block;
  padding-top: 115%; /* 100%/cos(30)  */
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

</div>
```